# Load CSS/JS file to textbox from a link

Tags: php, input, anchor, textinput

I am looking for suggestions and code samples to get a file and load it into a text area. Let me give a bit more of a detail.

My code searches for a file, and with in that file there is a array for additional CSS files. I am looking for a way to get the CSS file to be loaded to a text-area once you click on a button.

**Every file contains this:**

```
$CSS = array(file.css);
```

**Now, how can I get:**

```
<a href="file.css">CSS</a>
```

**or**

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">CSS</button>
```

**To load here:**

```
<textarea id="filecontent" name="filecontent" cols="80" rows="10">".$filecontent."</textarea>
```

Answer (score 3):

If its on same domain you can do it using jQuery

```
function myFunction(){
    $.ajax({ 
         url: 'css-url', 
         dataType: 'html', 
         cache: false, 
         success(d){ 
            $('#filecontent').val(d);
         });
}
```

easy as that.

Comment: Also remember this will come from different files, so the $CSS = array(file.css), will be the same. but not all the links will be the same.

Comment: Actually here are better samples of the links
`https://secure.site.com/forms/administration/first-year/index.php`  
`https://secure.site.com/forms/hatternet/deland/index.php`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the content of a file with: `file_get_contents($filename);`

```
<textarea id="filecontent" name="filecontent" cols="80" rows="10">".file_get_contents($filename)."</textarea>
```

But you should check, that nobody can open a file from your filesystem (Password file).